# How can I link two directories so that edits in one directory are reflected in the other directory?

Tags: symbolic-link

I have a website,`Foo`, running on Apache.  `Foo's` files are in the `/var/www` directory

`/var/www/foo`

Recently, I switched to developing with WebStorm. My webstorm directory is

`WebStorm_Projects/`.

I would like to set up a workflow so that I can use Webstorm to edit the site and have the changes reflected in `/var/www/Foo`

What is the best way to set this up?  Symlink (hard/soft)? How, can I  symlink the entire directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a soft link, as you cannot make a hard link with a directory. The syntax for this is `ln -s /var/www/Foo WebStorm_Projects`.